# ¿ Como determinar si un argumento de una función esta compuesta por mayúsculas, minúsculas o ambas?

Tags: javascript, funciones, comparaciones

Hola quiero saber si a hay algún método en las funciones para determinar si el argumento que la paso, seria una cadena de texto, esta compuesto de mayúsculas, minúsculas o si esta compuesta de mayúsculas o minúsculas.
Quiero hacer una función que me diga si los argumentos que la paso, en este caso una cadena de texto, y conseguir saber si tiene mayúsculas, minúsculas o ambas clases de letras.
Esto es lo que se me a ocurrido hasta el momento, pero me queda saber como distingo las letras(mayúsculas y minúsculas, o ambas)
Ya seria mucho, si consiguiera que al haber mayúsculas y minúsculas, me digera cuantas hay de cada clase.
Solo conseguí hace el planteamiento.
Una orientación de como proceder, o donde puedo buscar documentación. Busque en https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp y MDN pero no se si no busque lo bien, no encontré forma de conseguir mi propósito.

```js
function distingueLetras (argumentos) {
    if (argumentos == son minusculas) {
        console.log(`La palabra esta compuesta de minusculas`)
    }  else if(argumentos == son mayusculas){
        console.log('la esta compuesta de mayusculas')
    } 
    else {
        console.log(`la palabra esta compuesta de ${x} mayusculas y ${y} minusculas`)
    }

}
distingueLetras('hoy hace mucho calor')
distingueLetras('Aqui ESTAmos a 35 Grados')
distingueLetras('A LA PISCINA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés hacerlo usando `toLowerCase()` y `toUpperCase()` que devuelven el string en minúscula y mayúscula respectivamente, y [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/charCodeAt) que devuelve el número indicando del valor Unicode.

> El rango del código Unicode va del 0 al 1,114,111. Los primeros 128
>   códigos de Unicode encajan directamente con los códigos de caractéres
>   de la codificación [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)

Y viendo la tabla [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) se puede apreciar que los números del 65 hasta el 90 pertenecen a las letras mayúsculas del abecedario, mientras que del 97 al 122 pertenecen las letras minúsculas.

#### Por ejemplo:

```js
var unicode = "a".charCodeAt();
console.log(unicode);
```

Esto imprime 97. Teniendo eso, se puede recorrer el `string` para obtener las letras mayúsculas y minúsculas.

#### Solución:

```js
function distingueLetras (argumentos) {
  // compruebo si el string es igual al string puesto en minúsculas
  if (argumentos === argumentos.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('La palabra esta compuesta de minusculas');
  }
  // compruebo si el string es igual al string puesto en mayúsculas
  else if (argumentos === argumentos.toUpperCase()) {
    console.log('la esta compuesta de mayusculas');
  } else {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    
    // recorro el string
    for (var i = 0; i < argumentos.length; i++) {
      var charCode = argumentos[i].charCodeAt();
      
      // si pertenece a las mayúsculas
      if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
        x++;
      }
      // si pertenece a las minúsculas
      else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {
        y++;
      }
    }
    console.log(`la palabra esta compuesta de ${x} mayusculas y ${y} minusculas`)
  }

}

distingueLetras('hoy hace mucho calor')
distingueLetras('Aqui ESTAmos a 35 Grados')
distingueLetras('A LA PISCINA')
```

Comment: Perdón pero estoy sin tiempo para dejarte una mejor explicación, luego edito.

Comment: Gracias @Kleith, realmente funciona. Cuando tengas un rato, me podias explicar que significan los numeros: 65, 90, 97, 122 . Gracias

Comment: @MariCruz ahí me explayé un poco más para explicarte lo que hice.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrer toda la cadena (argumento) y preguntar si es mayúscula o minúscula, después decides qué hacer con el resultado

```
let mayus=0;
let minus=0;

for (int i=0;i<argumento.length;i++)
    {
        if(argumento.charAt(i).toUpperCase())
        {
            // Letras mayúsculas
             mayus++;
        }
        else if(argumento.charAt(i).toLowerCase())
        {
            // Letras minúsculas
             minus++;
        }
    }

 // Resto del código
```

Comment: Gracias por el interes @Gus, le di por buena la de Kleith, tu respuesta por lo que veo tambien funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Algo así:

```js
var palabra = 'PrUEbA';
var palabraArray = palabra.split('');
var upperCount = 0;
var lowerCount = 0;

palabraArray.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element == element.toUpperCase()) {
    upperCount++;
  }
  if (element == element.toLowerCase()){
    lowerCount++;
  }
});
if (upperCount > 0 && lowerCount == 0)
  alert('Todo el string esta compuesto de mayúsculas');
else if (lowerCount > 0 && upperCount == 0)
  alert('Todo el string esta compuesto de minúsculas');
else
  alert('El string esta compuesto por mayúsculas y minúsculas');
```

También lo hice para C#

```
        string palabra = "PrUeBA";
        char[] palabraArray = palabra.ToCharArray();
        int upperCount = 0;
        int lowerCount = 0;
        foreach (char letra in palabraArray)
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(letra))
                upperCount += 1;
            else
                lowerCount += 1;
        }
        if (upperCount > 0 && lowerCount == 0)
            Console.Write("Todo el string esta compuesto de mayúsculas");
        else if (lowerCount > 0 && upperCount == 0)
            Console.Write("Todo el string esta compuesto de minúsculas");
        else
            Console.Write("El string esta compuesto por mayúsculas y minúsculas");
```

Comment: Gracias @Victor Perdomo, ya le di por buena a Kleith, gracias por el apoyo